# How to handle angular 11 extract-i18n overriding existing translations?

Tags: angular, angular-i18n, angular-localize

So i have a angular 11 application where i just implemented localization with angulars default i18n middleware.

To create an initial file i just ran :

```
ng extract-i18n myprojectName --format xlf --output-path src/i18n  --out-file messages.da.xlf --progress
```

all was good and i got an messages.da.xlf file with default language translations.

Now i wanted to translate the application to english.

I copied messages.da.xlf file and named it messages.en.xlf and translated everything.

Everything is great an working right now.

But now i have an issue, next time i add an additional text to be translated english translation is not updated.

So my question is when i need to extend translation because of new features in the application how do i know which additional "fields" i have to add to all translation files and if there is a way to do it automaticaly?

Answer (score 4):

An alternative/new solution (to the unmaintained ngx-i18nsupport) is https://github.com/daniel-sc/ng-extract-i18n-merge

After installing via

```bash
ng add ng-extract-i18n-merge
```

translations will be extracted *and merged* with the command:

```bash
ng extract-i18n
```

(Transparency: I created this library.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way of doing this in Angular so you need a 3rd party tool. The only free tool that I have found is the now unmaintained [Xliffmerge](https://github.com/martinroob/ngx-i18nsupport/tree/master/projects/xliffmerge).
The documentation is targeting older versions of Angular but after some experimentation I found that it’s enough to install the `@ngx-i18nsupport/tooling` package:

```
npm install -D @ngx-i18nsupport/tooling --legacy-peer-deps
```

Then we can add new languages to the configurations in angular.json under `projects -> projectName -> architect -> xliffmerge`.

```
"xliffmerge": {
  "builder": "@ngx-i18nsupport/tooling:xliffmerge",
  "options": {
    "xliffmergeOptions": {
      "defaultLanguage": "en-US",
      "languages": ["nb"]
    }
  }
}
```

After adding new translations we can extract them and migrate them to our translation files by running this script:

```
ng extract-i18n && ng run projectName:xliffmerge
```

We get a couple of warnings running the script which tells us its working!

```
WARNING: merged 1 trans-units from master to "nb"
WARNING: please translate file "messages.nb.xlf" to target-language="nb"
```

I have written more about this on [my blog](https://blog.michaelkaren.dev/maintaining-multi-language-angular-applications-i18n).

Comment: Used to work with Angular 12, but Angular 13 :(

Comment: Sadly it only works with XLIFF.. for us using JSON, it's useless.