# Angular i18n Post Initial Translation

Tags: angular

I just started with Angular i18n and I am facing one problem with updating the translation files. It's like this:

1. For example, I created "How are you?" and i18n-ed it.
2. I got the "xlf" file and I can duplicate it and translate it into other desired language file.
3. Then I'd like to add "I'm fine" to original file and i18n-ed it.
4. But at this step, it will only update the original "xlf" file. It's not updating other translated file.

How can I extract the i18n to all the available "xlf" file with the i18n command?

Thank you!

Comment: "I created 'How are you?"'" How?  Where? Q: Could you please show some actual code?  And give the specific command you're using to "i18n-ed it"?

Comment: Here’s the exact question I’m asking for @paulsm4. Can you please check? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67235751/how-to-handle-angular-11-extract-i18n-overriding-existing-translations